# Why is map not working with json from api, while locally created json works fine? React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a local json file I created which I can map in my jsx without issue. When I pull similar json data from a news api however, I cannot map it. I get map is not a function error. I can pull in either data set in my useEffect in the NewsHome component based on commenting. It's probably some formatting issue but I have tried several things to no avail. What am I not doing correctly here?
Here is the component:

```
const NewsHome = () => {
  const [newsStories, setNewsStories] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // setNewsStories(getNews2()); //news api
    setNewsStories(NewsStories); //local json
  }, [NewsStories]);

  // console.log("newsStories api: ", newsStories); //news api
  console.log("newsStories local json: ", newsStories); //local json

  return (
    <Box
      style={{
        maxWidth: "90%",
      }}
    >
      <Typography
        style={{
          marginLeft: "0%",
        }}
        variant="h4"
      >
        News Site:
      </Typography>
      <Header />
      {newsStories.map((item, index) => (
        <Box
          style={{
            //display: "flex",
            marginTop: "50px",
          }}
          key={index}
        >
          <Box
            style={{
              maxWidth: "100%",
            }}
          >
            <Image key={index} src={images[item.urlToImage]}></Image>
            {/* <Image key={index} src={item.urlToImage}></Image> */}
          </Box>
          <Box
            style={{
              maxWidth: "90%",
              marginRight: "5px",
            }}
          >
            <Typography
              style={{
                marginBottom: "0px",
              }}
              variant="h5"
            >
              <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </Typography>
            <Typography>{item.description}</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default NewsHome;
```

These are the console outputs after being set by the newsStories hook.
Local json output that works is:

[image]

news api output response that doesn't work, along with error is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So `getNews2` returns a promise, which is not an array to be mapped.

But whenever it's fulfilled, it gives you the array.

So you need to wait for it to resolve, with either `then/catch` or `async/await`.

Try this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    getNews2().then(data=>setNewsStories(data))
  }, [NewsStories]);
```